# How to get text between two words in php

Tags: php

I have a string :

```
message to="919434556709@s.whatsapp.net" type="text" id="R6P3LMzq29vk0" t="1449760775" notify="SG"&gt;<br />tx&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;body&gt;&lt;/body&gt;<br />tx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/message&gt;<br /><br />
rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;message from="919788517593@s.whatsapp.net" type="text" id="jtOjHBip5NY+12" offline="0" t="1449674223" notify="Rohitashv singhal"&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;body&gt;Hiiiii&lt;/body&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/message&gt;<br /><br />
tx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;receipt type="read" to="919788517593@s.whatsapp.net" id="jtOjHBip5NY+12" t="1449674223"&gt;&lt;/receipt&gt;<br /><br />
rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;message from="919784517593@s.whatsapp.net" type="text" id="jtOjHBip5NY+13" offline="0" t="1449674223" notify="Rohitashv singhal"&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;body&gt;Hiiii&lt;/body&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/message&gt;<br /><br />
tx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;receipt type="read" to="919894597593@s.whatsapp.net" id="jtOjHBip5NY+13" t="1449674223"&gt;&lt;/receipt&gt;<br /><br />
rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;message from="91978451873@s.whatsapp.net" type="text" id="jtOjHBip5NY+12" offline="0" t="1449674223" notify="Rohitashv singhal"&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;body&gt;Hiiiii&lt;/body&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/message&gt;<br /><br />
tx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;receipt type="read" to="919789817593@s.whatsapp.net" id="jtOjHBip5NY+12" t="1449674223"&gt;&lt;/receipt&gt;<br /><br />
rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;message from="919784517593@s.whatsapp.net" type="text" id="jtOjHBip5NY+13" offline="0" t="1449674223" notify="Rohitashv singhal"&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;body&gt;Hiiii&lt;/body&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/message&gt;<br /><br />
tx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;receipt type="read" to="919789917593@s.whatsapp.net" id="jtOjHBip5NY+13" t="1449674223"&gt;&lt;/receipt&gt;<br /><br />
rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;message from="919784517999@s.whatsapp.net" type="text" id="jtOjHBip5NY+12" offline="0" t="1449674223" notify="Rohitashv singhal"&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;body&gt;Hiiiii&lt;/body&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/message&gt;<br /><br />
tx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;receipt type="read" to="919004517593@s.whatsapp.net" id="jtOjHBip5NY+12" t="1449674223"&gt;&lt;/receipt&gt;<br /><br />
rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;message from="919784517593@s.whatsapp.net" type="text" id="jtOjHBip5NY+13" offline="0" t="1449674223" notify="Rohitashv singhal"&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;body&gt;Hiiii&lt;/body&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/message&gt;<br /><br />
tx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;receipt type="read" to="919700517593@s.whatsapp.net" id="jtOjHBip5NY+13" t="1449674223"&gt;&lt;/receipt&gt;<br /><br />
rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;ib from="s.whatsapp.net"&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;offline count="6"&gt;&lt;/offline&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/ib&gt;<br /><br />
```

I want to get all text in between words `message from` and `/message`

If I use the following code :

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
                $string = " ".$string;
                $ini = strpos($string,$start);
                if ($ini == 0) return "";
                $ini += strlen($start);
                $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
                return substr($string,$ini,$len);
            }

          $res = cleanupXML($data);

          $parsed = get_string_between($res, 'message fro', "/message");

            echo $parsed;
```

It gives only one result. I want to get all occurance between these two words. How can I get this ?

Comment: Why not something like: `/message from=(.*)\/message/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use regex and php regex functions.

```
preg_match_all('/message from(.+)\/message/', $string, $variable);
```

it will give you an array which has 6 elements. Every element look like below sample:

```
message from="919788517593@s.whatsapp.net" type="text" id="jtOjHBip5NY+12"                     
offline="0" t="1449674223" notify="Rohitashv singhal"&gt;<br/>
rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;body&gt;Hiiiii&lt;/body&gt;<br />
rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/message
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
function getBetween($content,$start,$end){

    $r = explode($start, $content);

    if (isset($r[1])){

        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];

    }
    return '';
}
getBetween($res, 'message fro', "/message");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression and `preg_match_all()`:

```
$re = "/message from=(.*)\\/message/"; 
$str = "message to=\"919434556709@s.whatsapp.net\" type=\"text\" id=\"R6P3LMzq29vk0\" t=\"1449760775\" notify=\"SG\"&gt;<br />tx&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;body&gt;&lt;/body&gt;<br />tx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/message&gt;<br /><br />\nrx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;message from=\"919788517593@s.whatsapp.net\" type=\"text\" id=\"jtOjHBip5NY+12\" offline=\"0\" t=\"1449674223\" notify=\"Rohitashv singhal\"&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;body&gt;Hiiiii&lt;/body&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/message&gt;<br /><br />\ntx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;receipt type=\"read\" to=\"919788517593@s.whatsapp.net\" id=\"jtOjHBip5NY+12\" t=\"1449674223\"&gt;&lt;/receipt&gt;<br /><br />\nrx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;message from=\"919784517593@s.whatsapp.net\" type=\"text\" id=\"jtOjHBip5NY+13\" offline=\"0\" t=\"1449674223\" notify=\"Rohitashv singhal\"&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;body&gt;Hiiii&lt;/body&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/message&gt;<br /><br />\ntx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;receipt type=\"read\" to=\"919894597593@s.whatsapp.net\" id=\"jtOjHBip5NY+13\" t=\"1449674223\"&gt;&lt;/receipt&gt;<br /><br />\nrx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;message from=\"91978451873@s.whatsapp.net\" type=\"text\" id=\"jtOjHBip5NY+12\" offline=\"0\" t=\"1449674223\" notify=\"Rohitashv singhal\"&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;body&gt;Hiiiii&lt;/body&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/message&gt;<br /><br />\ntx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;receipt type=\"read\" to=\"919789817593@s.whatsapp.net\" id=\"jtOjHBip5NY+12\" t=\"1449674223\"&gt;&lt;/receipt&gt;<br /><br />\nrx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;message from=\"919784517593@s.whatsapp.net\" type=\"text\" id=\"jtOjHBip5NY+13\" offline=\"0\" t=\"1449674223\" notify=\"Rohitashv singhal\"&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;body&gt;Hiiii&lt;/body&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/message&gt;<br /><br />\ntx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;receipt type=\"read\" to=\"919789917593@s.whatsapp.net\" id=\"jtOjHBip5NY+13\" t=\"1449674223\"&gt;&lt;/receipt&gt;<br /><br />\nrx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;message from=\"919784517999@s.whatsapp.net\" type=\"text\" id=\"jtOjHBip5NY+12\" offline=\"0\" t=\"1449674223\" notify=\"Rohitashv singhal\"&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;body&gt;Hiiiii&lt;/body&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/message&gt;<br /><br />\ntx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;receipt type=\"read\" to=\"919004517593@s.whatsapp.net\" id=\"jtOjHBip5NY+12\" t=\"1449674223\"&gt;&lt;/receipt&gt;<br /><br />\nrx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;message from=\"919784517593@s.whatsapp.net\" type=\"text\" id=\"jtOjHBip5NY+13\" offline=\"0\" t=\"1449674223\" notify=\"Rohitashv singhal\"&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;body&gt;Hiiii&lt;/body&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/message&gt;<br /><br />\ntx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;receipt type=\"read\" to=\"919700517593@s.whatsapp.net\" id=\"jtOjHBip5NY+13\" t=\"1449674223\"&gt;&lt;/receipt&gt;<br /><br />\nrx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;ib from=\"s.whatsapp.net\"&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;offline count=\"6\"&gt;&lt;/offline&gt;<br />rx&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/ib&gt;<br /><br />\n"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```